# Can I avoid SharedArrayBuffer is NOT supported in your browser using nginx ssl reverse proxy?

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, iframe, sharedarraybuffer

I have a nginx docker handling the ssl, then a wordpress docker in http.

```
<iframe style="overflow: hidden; height: 100%; width: 100%;" src="https://test.com:3300" width="100%" height="100%" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin" allow="cross-origin-isolated"></iframe
```

Now I want to add an iframe in a page, this iframe is one instance of another docker I have, I can access this site without problems.

The problem is because I used a Iframe and I get this:

**SharedArrayBuffer is NOT supported in your browser**

in the nginx.conf I have this:

```
 server {
      listen 3300 ssl;

      server_name test.com;

      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/cert.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem;

      location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.0.226:3000;
        proxy_set_header Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "same-origin";
        proxy_set_header Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-corp";
        add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self' wss://test.com:3000/ws https://test.com:3300 https://test.com:3400 https://test.com:3000 https://test.com:3500 https://test.com:8040 https://test.com:8040/dicom-web/studies; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Authorization, Content-Type';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';
        client_max_body_size 100M;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';

      }
    }

    server {
      listen 3500 ssl;
      server_name test.com;

      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/cert.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem;


      location / {
       proxy_pass http://192.168.0.226:3400;
       proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto       $scheme;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_set_header Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "same-origin";
       proxy_set_header Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-corp";
       add_header Content-Security-Policy "frame-src 'self' wss://test.com:3000/ws https://test.com:3300 https://test.com:3400 https://test.com:3000 https://test.com:3500 https://test.com:8040 https://test.com:8040/dicom-web/studies; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'";
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers 'Authorization, Content-Type';
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials 'true';
       client_max_body_size 100M;
       proxy_buffering on;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
       proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';


      }

    }
```

Where I add        **proxy_set_header Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy "same-origin";** AND
**proxy_set_header Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-corp";**

Why is not possible to add an iframe like this?